# Rendering nested table rows in react

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table

I have a table, which shows `sales_item`.

A `sales_item` can have multiple `sales_item_option`.

And also, `sales_item_option` can have multiple `sales_item_option_attribute`.

`sales_item` with `sales_item_option` looks like below.

```
<tbody>
    <tr className={this.renderClassName()} id={this.props.id}>
        <td>{this.props.item_name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.quantity}</td> 
    </tr>
    {::this._renderItemOptions(sales.itemOptions)}
</tbody>
```

It works fine if there are no `sales_item_option_attribute` because it will render only `<tr>` tag, however, if there are `sales_item_option_attribute`, it breaks css of `sales_item_table`

`sales_item_option` looks like below.

```
var sales_item_option = false;
if (optionAttributes.length > 0) {
  var sales_item_option =
    <tbody>
        <tr className={this.renderClassName()} id={this.props.id}>
            <td>{this.props.option_name}</td>
            <td>{this.props.quantity}</td> 
        </tr>               
        {::this._renderListAttributes(optionAttributes)}
    </tbody>
}
else {
  var sales_item_option =
    <tr className={this.renderClassName()} id={this.props.id}>
      <td>{this.props.option_name}</td>
      <td>{this.props.quantity}</td> 
   </tr>
}
```

Since `render()` function in react requires to be wrapped in an enclosing tag, I used `<tbody>` to wrap. But it breaks css for table. I tried with other tags to wrap but it didn't help. How can I wrap it correctly so CSS works fine?

Comment: which version of react are you using

Comment: I'm using 15.4.2

Comment: use this https://github.com/gajus/react-aux

Comment: share your entire function and component code, so that we can check it out how you are return the data from the function to render method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in order to achieve what I want to do, I upgrade react version to 16.2 which supports `<Fragment />`.

```
const Fragment = React.Fragment;

var sales_item_option = false;
if (optionAttributes.length > 0) {
  var sales_item_option =
    <Fragment>
        <tr className={this.renderClassName()} id={this.props.id}>
            <td>{this.props.option_name}</td>
            <td>{this.props.quantity}</td> 
        </tr>               
        {::this._renderListAttributes(optionAttributes)}
    </Fragment>
}
else {
  var sales_item_option =
     <tr className={this.renderClassName()} id={this.props.id}>
        <td>{this.props.option_name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.quantity}</td> 
     </tr>
}
```

And it works fine.